# jQuery ajax POST data variable can hold max 199 json array

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, apache

I have a PHP web application that stores some data into array var called $excel.
That array contains around 500 - 600 rows (arrays).

When I try to pass that array as jSON using jQuery ajax like this:

```
$.ajax({
method: "POST",
url: "ajax/excel.php",
data: { "title": "Test", "data": <?php echo json_encode($excel); ?> },
dataType: "json"
}).done(function( data ) {
        console.log(data);
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(errorThrown+': '+textStatus);
});
```

I get only 199 rows in ajax/excel.php $_POST['data'] var.
I tried on different server and there I got 249 rows, so there must be some server config parametar that I just can't figure it out.

What i receive in ajax/excel.php as $_POST['data'] is

```
[
    ["1","2283","Name 1","Address 1","2714"],
    ["2","2200","Name 2","Address 2","2273"],
    ["3","1594","Name 3","Address 3","1718"],
    ...,
    ["199","3053","Name 199","Address 199","1709"]
]
```

Testing server is on Windows: Apache 2.4.18 (Win32) and PHP 5.6.26

Other server is on Linux: Apache 2.4.10 (Debian) and 5.6.29-0

Comment: Check max_input_vars

Comment: If your `$_POST['data']` have a valid JSON (with closing `]`) i don't think is a server config because if was a POST limit the JSON will arrive at the server broken, truncated...can you dump the `$excel` content (just to see the structure)?

Comment: $_POST['data'] have valid JSON. As Hussy Borad suggested it was a max_input_vars issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What "Hussy Board" said you can change in php.ini the **max_input_vars**, the default limit is 1000. Also checkout the **post_max_size**

Comment: **max_input_vars = 10000** solved my problem. It Was default to 1000. Thanks "Hussy Borad".

Comment: Solved my problem too, using AJAX+POST for saving documents.